# How to get just a portion of the results from Select-Object

Tags: powershell

I have a simple question, I hope someone can help...

if I run this command;

`get-pnpDevice -class display`

I get the expected results in a table format. It displays the Status, Class, FriendlyName, and InstanceID.

Next, I want to get just the InstanceID, which I can do with this command;

`Get-PnpDevice -Class display | Select-Object -Property instanceID`

But what I am stuck on is that I just want to get the inner portion of the result, not the full result. In other words, on my system, if I run the above command, I get the following result;

> PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_5912&SUBSYS_872F1043&REV_04\3&11583659&0&10
> PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1B81&SUBSYS_85971043&REV_A1\4&35D4F288&0&0008

But what I am trying to get is the result without the PCI\ and anything after and including the ampersand, for example, I dont want to see the &REV_04\3&11583659&0&10 or &REV_A1\4&35D4F288&0&0008

Any suggestions?

I tried the suggested calculated property and it returns something close to what I am trying to do, but not completely. I don't understand the calculated property, so please bear with me.... the result is as follows;

> InstanceID
>
> ---
>
> VEN_8086
> VEN_10DE

It seems to cut-off the results. I had a look through the Microsoft Select-Object documentation and it describes a little bit about calculated properties, but it doenst say anything about the -replace parameter, so I am a little lost about how to work with this and fix it for my use. Is there a better documentation you can point me to learn more about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need a calculated property with [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7).

```
Get-PnpDevice -Class display |
    Select-Object @{n='InstanceID';e={$_.InstanceId -replace '^PCI\\(.*?)&REV.*$','$1'}}
```

You can add other properties (comma-separated) along with the calculated property.

The `-replace` [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7) uses regex matching. The example here uses a capture group `(.*?)`, which is named capture group `1` (referenced later with `$1`) to capture all characters between `PCI\` and the first `&REV`. `^` is the start of a string. `$` is the end of the string. `.*` greedily matches zero or more characters. Since `\` is a special regex character, `\` is used to escape it resulting in `\\`.

The `e` or `expression` part of the calculated property contains a script block (code within `{}`). The script block contents perform a string replacement on each `InstanceId` value (`$_.InstanceId`).

Comment: thank you so much! I was busy studying regular expression witchcraft and going places fast!... seriously though, I wasn't. The updated fixed it. I really need to understand regex  and have added it to my list... it seems powerful.

Comment: There are several "flavors" of regex, which one is used for PS?  
Also you can start learning regex fairly quickly here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @user8891 PowerShell uses .NET regex.